# How to get first search result of google in Android

Tags: android, google-search

I am developing an Android application in which I need to add google search in such a way that whenever I pass a query, then it will return the first search in `Text` or `EditText`.

I tried to use `WebView` with below code for search, but this is returning all search result.. which is not serving my purpose.

```
String url="https://www.google.com/search?q=";
String query=null; //search query
url=url+query;
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

**My Requirement:** Suppose my query is *"who is the president of India"* then I should get *Pranab Mukherjee India, President* in return (Only top result)

Let me know if any further info required.

Regards,

Comment: You will probably not succeed with a webview here. You might try grabbing the whole html document and use jsoup to parse it.

Comment: Yeah, you're options are sign up for a developer key and use their API, or parse the content.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest

Comment: Thanks @Ascorbin and Grant Amos --- I'll go with parsing HTML content with jsoup.

Comment: @GrantAmos The API reference you posted is, as far as I understood it, only for the 'custom google search' that you can implement on your own website, not for querying google 'as a whole'.

Comment: @Ascorbin yup.  You're right, my bad.  Hasty response makes for bad answers.  Whoops!

Comment: @Ascorbin -- I tried to use jsoup to parse the html document but i am not getting the expected result.. not sure weather i am doing it right or not.